# div on click not fired during transition

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a simple div with an onclick function (Note I removed the content of the svg for readability):

```
<div id="sidebar-toggler">
  <svg></svg>
</div>

body.on('click', '#sidebar-toggler', function() {
  $('#sidebar').toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

this is working without a problem. But the div has also a transition to move a little to the right on hover:

```
&:hover
  left: 30px
  transition: left 0.4s ease-out
```

Now, sometimes (quite often) during the transition, the click event is not fired. Is this a common Problem and is there a solution to this?
What I have tried is to make a wrapper div around it, which is as big as the animations goes. But the Problem still exist.

What I have done is to add a wrapper around my round div like this:

```
( ) = Round div (button)
_________
|       | = wrapper
_________

transition
From:
_________
|( )    |
_________
To:
_________
|    ( )|
_________
```

And of course, I remapped the onclick to the wrapper. I though because the onclick is on the wrapper, and there is no transition on the wrapper, the onclick should be fired. But as said, no success so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `click` is very sensitive: you must click your mouse both down **and** up without the element moving.

You could use a mousedown or mouseup instead:

```
body.on('mouseup', '#sidebar-toggler', function() {
  $('#sidebar').toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

That wouldn't be dependent on movement.

The same would happen if you have a `onClick` method on a non-moving element, but you move your mouse. It wouldn't work since it's a drag instead of a click.

Comment: That's interesting to know, but why does my solution not work with the static wrapper? (Really interesting that it will be a drag with the transition, thank you a lot)

Comment: I think i got it, it seems that it doesn't matter on which element the onclick is, as long as the most front element under the mouse moves, it counts as drag ? Is this correct ? Do you know why the drag is relative mouse movement to an element, and not to the screen self ?